# MongoDB: Update function does not return a response in Python Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I built a small script in Flask that takes a file from my MongoDB with the `vkey` and updates the credits and level from the document:

```
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0.3ypph.mongodb.net/data?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        db=client["data"]
        col=db["user_currency"]
        h=hmac.new(b"test",b"",hashlib.sha3_512)
        credits_update=credits-cost
        h.update(vkey.encode("utf8"))
        try:
            db.col.update_one(
                {"vkey":h.hexdigest()},
                {"$set":{"credits":str(credits_update)}}
            )
            db.col.update_one(
                {"vkey":h.hexdigest()},
                {
                    "$set":{"level":count},
                    "$currentDate": { "lastModified": True }
                }
            )
        except:
            return redirect("/currency?error=02")
        else:
            return redirect("/currency?bought=lvlboost")
```

However, nothing is updated in MongoDB after execution and it only returns to the target page `/currency?bought=lvlboost`. I reloaded the database and also checked the vkey for correctness. Both are identical. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Start by getting the return value of each `update_one`; check the `matched_count` and `modified_count` to see if any updates are actually happening.

Comment: What were the results for those counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to your query, so that the return value will be added to that,

```
result = db.col.update_one(
    {"vkey":h.hexdigest()},
    {
        "$set":{ "level":count, "credits":str(credits_update) },
        "$currentDate": {"lastModified": True } 
    }
)
```

Now if you `print(result)` you can see the `matched_count` and the `modified_count`.

Doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns

Comment: Thanks, I have the counts now. Both are at 0. Sorry, that I could not found that directly. I'm still relatively new to the subject.

Comment: If `matched_count = 0`, then there is no entry matching with your query. Check your query `"vkey":h.hexdigest()`

Comment: I also thought it might be because of that. But I also tested a select method and it worked. The vkey matches the one in the database when printing.